# How to turn an expectation $E[A]$ into a conditional expectation, e.g., $E[A|B=1]$?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, expected-value, conditional-expectation, independence

How can you turn an expectation $E[A]$ into a conditional expectation, e.g., $E[A|B=1]$, where:

- A - continuous random variable, $A \in (-100, 1000)$
- B - discrete r.v., $B \in {0, 1}$
- A and B are DEPENDENT.

For instance:

- I have estimate $E[A]$ out of a fitted estimator but my decision
  making formula requires $[A|B=1]$.
- I do have historical observations for $A|B=0$ and for $A|B=1$.

Is there some way to "adjust" / multiply the expectation $E[A]$ with some calculated parameter $\theta$ calculated on historical data for it to be at least theoretically close to the conditional expectation $E[A|B=1]$? (I would expect the formula to look somewhat similar to this:

- $E[A|B=1] = E[A] \cdot \theta$

What is the correct way to approach this problem?

(Thank you for your patience)

Comment: One of the probability axioms says that when $C=A\cup B$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset,$ then $\Pr(C)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B).$ It applies to conditional probabilities, too.  Use it.

Comment: If you have historical observations of A when B = 1 why cannot you just take the average of those historical observations and use that as an estimate of $E[A|B=1]$?

Comment: There are more things to consider when predicting E[A], e.g. there is time element and hence the regressor takes many more features. Now, I am trying to reuse this well trained regressor and i do not have the resources to train regressor E[A|B=1], but the decision task requires that I use E[A|B=1] instead of E[A] and I am trying to  figure out what the best course of action would be. (Thanks for your patience)